# randomly assign values to two matrix based on conditions in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I have two matrix: old1 and gl1, i want to assign the values from the two matrix into another two new matrix. i used the method: 1) rbind the two matrix; 2) use sample function to random assign the values; 3) seperate the large matrix into two new matrix. Here are the codes:

```
 library(ms.sev)

    ### old Global MSSS matrix
    data(oldMsss)

    old <- data.matrix(oldMsss)

    old1 <- old[-1,-1]

    ## use the global MSSS
    data(globalMsss)

    gl <- data.matrix(globalMsss)

    gl1 <- gl[,-1]

    ## combine
    tc <- rbind(gl1,old1)

    set.seed(1)

    n.permutations = 5
    sum.table = rep(1,n.permutations)

    for(j in 1:n.permutations) {
        print(j)

        t1 <- matrix(sample(tc),nrow=60)
        tf <- t1[1:30,]
        tf1 <- t1[31:60,]
        sum.table[j] <- sum(tf1-tf)

    }
```

By checking the matrix in details, i noticed that for both old1 and gl1, from EDSS.0.0 to EDSS.9.5, the value should increase (for example, from 0.91 to 10 for gl1), same for the y, the value should decrease (for example, from 0.91 to 0.07 for gl1).

However, my method above is not correct as it didn't take the correlation into account when assigning the values. Any idea how to assign the values to new matrix but followed similar pattern?

Many thanks...

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you want exactly.If you want to randomly assign values from two matrices to another matrix, why should the correlation matter?

Comment: Hi Florian, sorry for the confusing. i have removed the word 'randomly'. it is more like assign values to two new matrix following the pattern described above

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that your data are multivariate gaussian, you could do

```
sample_similar_patern <- function(mat) {
  MASS::mvrnorm(n = nrow(mat), mu = colMeans(mat), Sigma = cov(mat))
}

for(j in 1:n.permutations) {
  print(j)

  tf <- sample_similar_patern(gl1)
  tf1 <- sample_similar_patern(old1)

  sum.table[j] <- sum(tf1-tf)
}
```

Comment: The new matrix will be based on the values of gl1 and old1, but reallocate these values that follow the same pattern into two new matrix. (For example, 0.91 and 0.86 in gl1, 0.67 and 0.53 in old1. the new matrix would be 0.91,0.67 vs 0.86, 0.53, or 0.91,0.53 vs 0.86, 0.67). Any idea how to do that?...